# how to compare numeric string in snowflake

Tags: string, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

in snowflake the number data type supports 38 digits length.
to store the values more than 38 digits ,i have used the varchar data type.
I have two set of tables ,

table1:

- Block varchar
- numberstart varchar
- numberend varchar

table2

- number varchar

i want see the block details from table1 where table2.number exist between table1.numberstart and table2.numberend

here i have two issues

1. string comparison giving wrong output.
2. i can not convert it into number using cast or to_number function, because the string values are more than 38 digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could `LPAD` values to common size and then perform string comparison

```
SELECT*
FROM table2 t2
JOIN table1 t1
  ON LPAD(t2.number, 50, '0') BETWEEN LPAD(t1.numberstart, 50, '0') 
                                  AND LPAD(t1.numberend,   50, '0');
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7fa88b429c2cb55f363ebdd441ffe1c6)

It is simplified case, if negative numbers or fractions are involved it will not work.